# Let be $L$ tangent on P to a nonsingular cubic curve $C$. Show that L intersects C at a unique single point.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

I have to do it using Bezout's theorem. I have a question in my solution, Can I asumme that $I(P,L \bigcap C)=2$ because $L$ is tangent on $P$ to C?... If it is like this, the Bezout's theorem would implies that there is only  another point $P_1$ with $I(P_1,L\bigcap C)=1$ ....If it is not like this... can someone help me?

.. thanks...

Comment: The tangent might intersect the curve to a higher order than $2$. Consider, for example, the curve $y=x^3$ and the $x$-axis. In such a case, the "other" intersection point is the point $P$ of tangency (so it isn't really *another* point).